# calling function inside function without parameters

Tags: c, function, parameters, keil

Calling a function without calling its parameters inside another function is a little bit confusing as follows:

```
ppp = pppos_create(&ppp_netif, output_cb, status_cb, 0);
```

Where `output_cb` and `status_cb` are functions that their parameters are not set and their definitions must be written in upper lines than the line they are called.

Function definitions:

```
static void status_cb(ppp_pcb *pcb, int err_code, void *ctx) {

    struct netif *pppif = ppp_netif(pcb);

    switch(err_code) {
        case PPPERR_NONE: {
            printf("status_cb: Connected\n");
            printf("   our_ipaddr  = %s\r\n", ipaddr_ntoa(&pppif->ip_addr));
            printf("   his_ipaddr  = %s\r\n", ipaddr_ntoa(&pppif->gw));
            printf("   netmask     = %s\r\n", ipaddr_ntoa(&pppif->
            break;
        }
        case PPPERR_PARAM: {
            printf("status_cb: Invalid parameter\r\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

static u32_t output_cb(ppp_pcb *pcb, u8_t *data, u32_t len, void *ctx)
{
    return HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, data, sizeof(data));
}

int main(void)
{
    ppp = pppos_create(&ppp_netif, output_cb, status_cb, 0);
}
```

What does `status_cb` print without giving an `err_code` as a parameter? When or how will `status_cb` and `output_cb` be evaluated?

Where `pppos_create`is defined as follows:

```
ppp_pcb *pppos_create(struct netif *pppif, pppos_output_cb_fn output_cb,
       ppp_link_status_cb_fn link_status_cb, void *ctx_cb)
{
    pppos_pcb *pppos;
    ppp_pcb *ppp;

    pppos = (pppos_pcb *)LWIP_MEMPOOL_ALLOC(PPPOS_PCB);
    if (pppos == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ppp = ppp_new(pppif, &pppos_callbacks, pppos, link_status_cb, ctx_cb);
    if (ppp == NULL) {
        LWIP_MEMPOOL_FREE(PPPOS_PCB, pppos);
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(pppos, 0, sizeof(pppos_pcb));
    pppos->ppp = ppp;
    pppos->output_cb = output_cb;
    return ppp;
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: can you attach the code body for `pppos_create()` as well?

Comment: Hard to say unless we see what `pppos_create` look like

Comment: Sirs, I have attached, I can attach more as you wish, thank you.

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275327/why-lcp-negotiation-over-pppos-session-doesnt-start-via-lwip-between-stm32f7-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Calling a function without calling its parameters inside another function is a little bit confusing as follows:
>
> ```
> ppp = pppos_create(&ppp_netif, output_cb, status_cb, 0);
> ```
>
> Where output_cb and status_cb are functions [...]

`output_cb` and `status_cb` are *not* function *calls*, but rather function *pointers*.  A function's name without the parenthesised parameter list is a pointer to the function not a call to it.  A function pointer allows a function to be called without knowledge of which function will be called at compile/link time.  In this case that are used as *callbacks* so that a predefined library function can call a user application function.

A simple example of a function pointer:

Given:

```
int someFunction( int arg ) 
{
    return( arg ) ;
}
```

The you can declare a function pointer `fp` variable thus:

```
int (*fp)(int) = someFunction ;
```

You can then call `someFunction` function through `fp` thus:

```
int x = fp( 2 ) ;
```

> What does status_cb print without giving an err_code as a parameter? When or how will status_cb and output_cb be evaluated?

The arguments to the functions are provided at the time they are called, not the time they are passed to `pppos_create()`. In `pppos_create()`, they are assigned to the `output_cb` and `,`link_status_cb`parameters respectively.  They have type`pppos_output_cb_fn`and`ppp_link_status_cb_fn`which will be`typedef`s for function pointer types for example:

```
typedef void (*ppp_link_status_cb_fn)(ppp_pcb *, int, void*);
```

In this case `pppos_create()` does not call these functions; rather it is assigning them to members of data structures `pppos` and `ppp` which will presumably be called later whenever the associated PPP events occur (I am guessing that this is a point-to-point protocol related function).  In this case they are a way of providing user defined handling to a pre-defined function.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for paying attention and giving a full answer that erases all the questions about the function pointers in the most general way; however, I am setting a variable depending on the switch case in the `output_cb` function and realized that it is never been set. Is it why that I am not able to properly create the PPPoS session or the associated PPP event never occurs? More specifically, how may I know which associated event calls that `output_cb` function; so that I will not have to debug since GSM modem will not break out the connection?

Comment: Additionally, I have to check the error code globally and I even cannot assign it to `output_cb`. How will I be able to see that error code and do process according to it? Kind Regards

Comment: @SarpEnginDaltaban : You have gone from a very general question about function pointers to very specific questions about an API.  You would do better to post a new question about these issues.  Passing an initialised callback pointer to an API is unlikely to end well.